# Laravel5) How to store the average value of a particular column by Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

An article has multiple comments, and each comment has a score column.

When a new comment (score) is added to an article, I want to store the average of all comments in article.

Since the score is stored in each comment, in this case-
1. the score of all comments and new comments are added up, and divided by the number of comments.
2. Or the average value of the comments stored in article may be multiplied by (the number of comments-1), followed by adding the score of the new comment and dividing it by the number of comments.

I tried to code this in laravel querybuilder, so difficult.
How do I code in Query Builder?
thanks in advance your help.

```
MariaDB []> desc articles;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| title      | varchar(191)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| content    | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| average_score      | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


MariaDB []> desc comments;
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id          | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id        | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| commentable_type | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commentable_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content          | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| score            | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

CommentsController.php

```
public function store(CommentsRequest $request, Article $article)
{       
    $comment = $article->comments()->create(array_merge(
        $request->all(),
        ['user_id' => 'Guest']
    ));

    #Here, the average value of comments is stored in $ article
...
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to store the average, you could calculate average at run time

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate avg of a particular column using this:

```
$avg = Model::avg('column_name');
```

So just add a new comment then calculate avg where comments belong to that id. Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

I recommend no use an avg column. Can be calculated with

```
$article->comments->avg('score')
```